# Rename variables to make the XML ids cleaner

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, rename

I've been wanting to make the code cleaner, but I do not give it away. I mean...

To name the ids of the views in the XML I use Hungarian notation like this:

`<WHAT> <WHERE> <DESCRIPTION> <SIZE>`

For example: `tvExampleSectionEmptyBig`,`tvExampleSectionEmptySmall`

Previously, using `Butter Knife`, I did not get too much coding because to do the bindings, I did things like this:

```
@BindView (R.id.tvExampleSectionEmptyBig) TextView tvEmptyBig;
@BindView (R.id.tvExampleSectionEmptySmall) TextView tvEmptySmall;
```

The code was much clearer and more reusable since the Hungarian notation used to avoid the confrontation between ids with the same name in different activities, fragments, etc. it was not present in practice more than in XML.

**What's going on?**

Kotlin has `synthetic`, which makes your life easier since with putting the id of the view, the binding is done directly, but with such long ids the code is very dirty ... Besides, makes sense that all the views I use in an activity called `ExampleSectionActivity`, contain within its variable name`ExampleSection`?

**What would I like?**

Surely there are better solutions that, but initially, what I feel is to implement a way to **rename variables** by removing a given `String`. As I follow a convention in all the names of the ids, it would be something internally in this way:

```
val tvEmptyBig = tvExampleSectionEmptyBig
val tvEmptySmall = tvExampleSectionEmptySmall
```

But of course, I would like to do it in an automated way.

On the other hand, I already tried naming the ids without the  and to be careful with the imports, but for the moment `synthetic` fails very occasionally in this respect and I had to rebuild constantly. Especially if I open another instance of Android Studio, which I usually do quite often for consulting other projects I have.

Any idea? :-)

Comment: *but for the moment synthetic fails very occasionally in this respect and I had to rebuild constantly* - this is a bug and will be fixed in the next release of AS. For your question, if you need the long name "tvExampleSectionEmptySmall" in xml, why don't you also need it in code? Also why do you feel that having long variable names makes the code dirty? It's better to be expressive than to have short names just to have short names

Comment: I also need it in code. I would like to rename those longs variable names for being more readable.

Comment: I tried to explain in the post. For example: I do not need the string `ExampleSection` within a variable called `tvExampleSectionEmptyBig` inside an activity called `ExampleSectionActivity`. It would be better the name `tvEmptyBig`.

Comment: why is it called tvExampleSectionEmptyBig in the xml then? Why not tvEmptyBig

Comment: 2 reasons: if I have other view called with the same name in other XML, we can have conficts. And the other one, if I refactor the name of the variable in one XML, I will change the name of the other variable in other XML directly.

Comment: I am watching that for a few weeks, the last updates are working very well with ambiguities with synthetic imports, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the easies and the most clean thing you can do is this:

```
private val myTextView: TextView
    get() = f_layoyt_text_view
```

This way you don't have to use ridiculous, at least in 2018, ButterKnife and even more inconvenient `findViewById`.

Comment: @GabrielMoreno it depends on what do you mean by that?

Comment: I want to apply in all my activities and fragments. I would like a way to loop all views and obtain the renamed variables directly.

Answer (score 0):

For a few weeks, I already take for granted, that with the latest stable updates of Android Studio, there is no problem with repeating names of ids in different activities or fragments. Therefore, **it is no longer necessary to put long variable names**. Only there is to pay a little bit of attention to the imports, everything works like a charm, more readable and reusable. :-)